# Incorrect content type using rackspace form post

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am using form post method to post some files to one of my containers on rackspace. Problem is if i upload a pdf first and then a png in 1 go, It is trying to open png in pdf viewer. Upon checking I came to know that the "Content-type" was set to "application/pdf" for png.

My form is something like

```
<form id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" action="action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="rediredt url">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="max_file_size">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="max_file_count">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="expires" id="rack_expire">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="signature" id="rack_signature">

<div class="contentRow fileUploadWrap">
<p><input id="file2" type="file" name="file_1"></p>
<p><input id="file2" type="file" name="file_2"></p>
<p><input id="file3" type="file" name="file_3"></p>
<p><input id="file4" type="file" name="file_4"></p>
<p><input id="file5" type="file" name="file_5"></p>
<div class="contentRow">
<div class="submit"><input id="uploadFilesBtn" class="btn btn--primary" type="submit" value="Upload"></div> </div>
</div>

</form>
```

I cant find a way to set the content type for the files being uploaded. Is there any way i can fix this.

Comment: On what browser/version/OS are you observing this behavior?

Comment: i tried on windows, mac and for browsers chrome and firefox

Comment: @nOmi How did you end up doing this?

Comment: I couldn't actually, tried contacting rackspace, they said you can send the content type with the data but In my case I m not sure how can I for multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only workaround i found for this is to update the content type of the uploaded files using api methods [mentioned here](https://docs.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/storage-api-reference/object-services-operations#create-or-update-object-metadata).

I was already saving the file names so i just did a post CURL to update the info and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` instead of `input` and specify the filename like this

```
formData.append('userfile[]', myFileInput.files[0], 'doc1.pdf');
formData.append('userfile[]', myFileInput.files[1], 'image1.png');
```

The browser will identify the file type (content-type) and open the file accordingly, results may be different from browser to another, but you can relay on it for common file formats.

As specify in [FormData Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

> If you specify a Blob as the data to append to the FormData object, the filename that will be reported to the server in the "Content-Disposition" header used to vary from browser to browser.